# integer to string conversion in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

I have the following code --

```
    <td ng-class="{danger:values.capacity>threshold}">{{values.capacity}}</td>
```

The problem is that `values.capacity` has is a string ("70%") and threshold is an int (70). Is there any way I can make the conversion in the HTML?

Comment: HTML has no concept of data types. What you're really asking "How do I do this with angular and/or javascript".

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `parseInt()` function to convert the 70% to 70 (int).

just call in your controller:

```
$scope.values.capacity = parseInt($scope.values.capacity, 10);
```

Comment: Setting radix 10 explicitly would be better for old browsers: `parseInt(str,10)`

Comment: Yeah if you need to support < IE8 you should use the radix parameter. I have edited my answer